# Collection was mutated while being enumerated when [mapView addOverlay:overlayPolygon];

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, android-mapview

i tired to look over SF for solution, but can't find a solution.
maybe i missed it please help.

i tried to check out a user pinpoint with polygon by looping through all the KMLs.
the app always crash @ this point:

```
            [mapView addOverlay:overlayPolygon];

            // zoom the map to the polygon bounds
            [mapView setVisibleMapRect:overlayPolygon.boundingMapRect animated:YES];
```

problem code:

```
//create KML in hidden Mapview
-(void)loadKML:(NSMutableArray *)kmlNameArray
{    
    //dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();


    //remove polygon and redraw again.
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinEnd) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    [mapView removeOverlays:mapView.overlays];
    [inUserRangeArray removeAllObjects];
    [inUserRangeArrayObjectIndex removeAllObjects];
    [scrollview removeFromSuperview];
    [pageControl removeFromSuperview];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBegin) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
    NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];   


    for (int e=0; e<[kmlNameArray count]; e++) 
    {        
        //NSString *kmlNameStr = [kmlNameArray objectAtIndex:e];
        Frog *kmlID = [self.fs objectAtIndex:e];
        self.kmlID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",kmlID.fID];
        self.kmlIDObjectIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",e];

        NSLog(@"asasas %@",kmlIDObjectIndex);

        //NSLog(@"KML items %@", kmlNameStr);          
        //NSLog(@"KML ID %@", kmlID);
        //NSLog(@"KML file Path %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data/%@/%@", docDirectory,self.kmlID,[kmlNameArray objectAtIndex:e]]);


        SimpleKML *kml = [SimpleKML KMLWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data/%@/%@", docDirectory,self.kmlID,[kmlNameArray objectAtIndex:e]]error:NULL];

        // look for a document feature in it per the KML spec


        //        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        if (kml.feature && [kml.feature isKindOfClass:[SimpleKMLDocument class]])
        {// see if the document has features of its own
            for (SimpleKMLFeature *feature in ((SimpleKMLContainer *)kml.feature).features)
            {// otherwise, see if we have any placemark features with a polygon
                if ([feature isKindOfClass:[SimpleKMLPlacemark class]] && ((SimpleKMLPlacemark *)feature).polygon)
                {
                    SimpleKMLPolygon *polygon = (SimpleKMLPolygon *)((SimpleKMLPlacemark *)feature).polygon;
                    SimpleKMLLinearRing *outerRing = polygon.outerBoundary;
                    //points[i], i = number of coordinates
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D points[[outerRing.coordinates count]];
                    NSUInteger i = 0;
                    for (CLLocation *coordinate in outerRing.coordinates)
                    { 
                        points[i++] = coordinate.coordinate;
                    }
                    // create a polygon annotation for it
                    self.overlayPolygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:[outerRing.coordinates count]];

                    //crash here
                    [mapView addOverlay:overlayPolygon];

                    // zoom the map to the polygon bounds
                    [mapView setVisibleMapRect:overlayPolygon.boundingMapRect animated:YES];

                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: It seems that maybe the error is telling you that the internals of [mapView addOverlay:] is altering the the collection of features in the SimpleKMLContainer whilst being enumerated through. Have you tried switching the for loop through the features from the fast enumeration style or add the overlayPolgon to a temporary array and add to the mapView once the enumeration has completed?

Comment: Hi Brett,
Thanks for the reply. No i did not tried, how will i do it ?
Do u mind sharing a sample code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you loop over the array, you can create a new array with the elements. So when the original looped array is mutated (either by you, or by its owner) the array you loop over stays intact.

```
NSArray *theFeatures = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:((SimpleKMLContainer *)kml.feature).features];
for (SimpleKMLFeature *feature in theFeatures) {

}
```

So in case of looping over the `SimpleKMLContainer` features directly, you create a temporary new array with those features, and loop over that array.

Because you experience a crash on `addOverlay:` you must somehow be looping over the entire overlay collection. I don't see that directly in your code, so I assume that the `features` collection is somehow tied to the map kit overlays.

Comment: It is worth noting that `arrayWithArray` copies the array itself, but not the objects inside it (it retains them). Just a good to know!

Comment: changed the code a little to use your variables. Basically just create a temporary array first instead of directly looping over the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could is not use the fast enumeration version of the `for`. So try replacing this:

```
for (SimpleKMLFeature *feature in ((SimpleKMLContainer *)kml.feature).features)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

with this:

```
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [((SimpleKMLContainer *)kml.feature).features count]; index++)
{
    SimpleKMLFeature *feature = [((SimpleKMLContainer *)kml.feature).features objectAtIndex:index];
    // Your code here
}
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

better check out the sample code called [HazardMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049) to see how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the same issue by defining the Array I was enumerating as a normal `NSArray` instead of a `NSMutableArray`.

That did the trick for me.